# Is there a word that means cheating but legitimate?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means cheating and legitimate at the same time?

For example: I play a quiz game and set the number of questions to one. So, I get 100% of my answers correct. That's cheating, but it's legit.

So how do I describe what I did in one word?

Comment: The above scenario you have specified is not at all cheating. Because, if you answer that single question wrongly, you are 100% lost. So, it's not cheating but legitimate. (Ethical)

Comment: Loading the dice,using a marked deck, stacking the cards.

Comment: "Loading the dice,using a marked deck, stacking the cards" are not legitimate.

Comment: Depends on context. In the context of regulation and government incentives/dis-incentives, you often see *gaming the system* as per Prem's answer below. In sports it would be *gamesmanship* as per Papa Poule's answer. In the context of taxation the usual word is *loophole* as per Steve Jessop's answer.

Comment: Some definitions of "to hack" may fit.

Comment: Rounding. As when the package of food says 0 grams of fat (means less then .5 of a gram).

Comment: "Gamesmanship" is what you're looking for.

Comment: The best common usage word someone mentioned is "trick". You use a "trick" to legitimately win, or "trick" your opponents.

Comment: I consider 'exam technique' to be an aloof term to refer to the term you're looking for

Comment: Related: [What is a word for annoying behavior which decreases enjoyment for the other players in a game?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/181836/26083)

Comment: What is meant by "legit" in this question? Breaking the quiz in your example isn't a legitimate (i.e. *conforming to the law or rules*) way of winning because it's effectively changing the rules rather than conforming to them. Unless it's part of a greater contest, e.g. a contest to hack the quiz (in which the contest rules would permit changing the quiz's internal rules), this question is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Not enough rep to answer so.. In gaming circles the common word is "move". Usage "The Player made a move". A "move" can be legit, gray area cheating or just plain cheating. The word is used in poker for example when the move made is not completely on the up and up.

Comment: "Gaming the system" might work. Also "dirty pool", meaning the kind of pool playing that takes advantage of every rule to screw your opponent rather than just relying on the simple skill of sinking balls.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we call that "creative winning."

Comment: What in school is called "cheating" in the real world is oftentimes called "collaborating" ;-)

Comment: It's an interesting observation that there are ***many such terms*** available in our world for the quality asked about here  :/

Answer (score 65):

When a game has rules, breaking the rules is known as cheating. But some folks look at the wording (letter) of the rules and try to cheat without breaking the rules. So there is the concept of intent (spirit) of the rules. Folks who cheat, but do not break the rules, are breaking the spirit of the rules.

Some other phrases used are:

- *rules lawyering*
- *gaming the system*
- *exploiting technicalities/loopholes/ambiguous language*

([Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_and_spirit_of_the_law))

Answer (score 44):

You've *exploited* a *loophole* in the rules.

Comment: This is the correct term for games; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_%28video_gaming%29

Answer (score 24):

You are "gaming" the system. Gaming implies that you are playing within the rules but in the way that the rule writers did not intend or expect.

Answer (score 20):

“[Gamesmanship](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gamesmanship)” is a single-word noun that seems to describe what you are up to.

I don’t think an adjective currently exists for this noun, but perhaps somewhere between “sportsmanlike”  and “unsportsmanlike” you could coin and find a place for “gamesmanlike.”

Phrases could include “gaming/playing the system,” “bending the rules,” or “exploiting technicalities/a technicality.”

Answer (score 17):

In this case it seems like you are outsmarting the system, so how about:

**Circumvention**

> to avoid (defeat, failure, unpleasantness, etc.) by artfulness or
>   deception; avoid by anticipating or outwitting

from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/circumvent)

**Bypass**

> to go around or avoid (a city, obstruction, problem, etc)

from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bypass)

Answer (score 5):

I would call that [**cheap**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheap&defid=1256751). The act itself would be **employing a cheap tactic**. Alternatively, your strategy could be seen as an [**exploit**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_%28video_gaming%29), in which case you would be **exploiting**.

Answer (score 2):

Cheating or bypassing or exploiting all the possibilities and shortcuts is called 'hacking'.

In your situation you **'hacked'** the quiz, if you need one word.

There is an expression **'to work something around'** or **'to find a workaround'**

This type of activity, exploiting workarounds and shortcuts is described as **'life hacks'**

Answer (score 1):

I think an **[expedient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expedient)** may suggest a neutral connotation:

> - Something that is a means to an end, especially when based on self-interest: *compromised only as an expedient to boost his career.* (AHD)

The Free Dictionary

also, but with stronger connotation, a [dodge](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dodge):

> - A cunning trick or dishonest act, in particular one intended to avoid something unpleasant:

(ODO)

Comment: How about just *trick?*

Comment: @JimReynolds I think "trick" is the best word for this in terms of common usage. You use a "trick" to win the game, or you "trick" your opponents. Please make this a unique answer and post when you have.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear in your example exactly who you're supposed to be cheating. But you can try:

**outwit** (or outsmart)

> to defeat somebody/something or gain an advantage over them by doing something clever

In my opinion, it doesn't have a very negative connotation.

Source - [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/outwit)

Answer (score 1):

You have [taken advantage](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/take+advantage+of) of the rules.

Answer (score 1):

*Literal interpretation/bending the rules* might also work.

> Roll a dice, the highest number wins.
>
> Player 1 rolls a six.
> Player 2 rolls a five.
> Player 3 takes out a 20 sided dice and rolls a 19.

Player 3 is not cheating, since the rules don't state what dice to roll, but that's not what the rules intended.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to gaming the system, **playing the system** sounds more natural to me in British English.

As well as exploiting a loophole in the rules, I'd like to offer **creative interpretation of the rules** and **abuse of the rules.**

The International Obfuscated C Code Contest (a programming contest) offers a an award for **"worst abuse of the rules"** which was famously won one year by a quine (self-replicating program) which consisted of an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

Related (in terms of being popular and accepted)

***to bank*** (slang)

> [The American Slang Dictionary](https://books.google.ca/books?id=uLNZAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA25&dq=%22play%20against%20the%20bank%22%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ooMqVZ-wDoffsASHjoDACA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22play%20against%20the%20bank%22%20slang&f=false) - Page 25 James Maitland - 1891
>
> Bank, "to play" (Am.), means **to play against the bank or gambling
>   house.**

Answer (score 0):

*"creative [ something ] "* could also be an option. This is cheating,  but per the rules.

Answer (score 0):

**Gaming**

As in Gaming the System. You technically following the *rules* but not the *intent*.

Answer (score 0):

A clause used by a former President of the United States to describe this approach to making a comment or a statement is, "legally accurate but not volunteering information."

Answer (score 0):

**Cheesing** is one that's gained popularity recently, particularly in the gaming community, but I think it can be applied to anything. It refers to exploiting the game in a way that goes against the spirit of the game, whilst still being technically not cheating or breaking any rules.

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of Metagaming.

You're not cheating at the game though, since you made up the rules.  If you want to expand the rules and say that the inherent difficulty of the quiz matters then you would have a low score.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps "Gaining an edge" or "Gaining an advantage".

Comment: There is no cheating implied there.

Answer (score -4):

What about one of these: Fabricate
Embellish
Tailor
Doctor
Refine

Comment: three of these fail the "legitimate" test and the other two need some information on how and why they could fit as answers....