# Word to describe hidden intentions

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a term that describes a certain behavior. The example I have is in a situation where a person has malicious intent, but pretends to be innocent or even helpful. For example, if you have a “friend” that calls your wife, knowing you’re out of town. When confronted, they were just checking in on her. I am interested in a term that describes both the intent, and the type of response.

A second example could be a security guard groping a woman during a search. When confronted the response is that it was a frisk for everyone’s safety. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: [a phrase for an underhanded malicious act that appears to be done in good faith](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287463/a-phrase-for-an-underhanded-malicious-act-that-appears-to-be-done-in-good-faith/287927#287927) So only SW answers will be in good faith here.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for -

> ## Ulterior
>
> > : existing beyond what is obvious or admitted; intentionally hidden.

([From Lexico](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/ulterior))

Therefore, "***ulterior motive***" might fit your given context -

> ## Ulterior motive
>
> > An alternative or extrinsic reason for doing something, especially
> >     when concealed or when differing from the stated or apparent reason.

([From Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ulterior_motive))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> **ruse**
>  <sub>NOUN COUNTABLE</sub>
>
> A plan or trick for hiding your true intentions
>
> <sub>Source: [*Macmillan
>   Dictionary*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/ruse)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The action of the “friend” in your example could be termed as '***ostensible***', which means '*appearing to be one thing when it is really something else*'.

Answer (score 0):

How about Dissemble:

> To puts on a false appearance: conceal facts, intentions, or feelings under some pretense.

> To disguise or conceal one's real nature, motives, or feelings behind a false appearance.

> A dissembler is one who conceals his opinions, character, etc., under a false appearance; one who pretends that a thing which it is not.

Answer (score -1):

[*Hidden agenda*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hidden-agenda) is an expression that may fit your context:

> If you say that someone has a hidden agenda, you are criticizing them because you think they are secretly trying to achieve or cause a particular thing, while they appear to be doing something else.

(Collins)