# A person who begs for help but doesn't return the favor

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

I play a game and need a word for the following situation.

What do you call a person who asks, and begs multiple times daily and impatiently for items (gear, weapons, weapon upgrades, runs through dungeons) and swears loyalty to your guild or raids team to help and or pay for items later but does nothing in return? Then when you confront that person, they ‘unfriend’ you and leave your guild.

Comment: Loosely related: [What is a word for annoying behavior which decreases enjoyment for the other players in a game?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181836/what-is-a-word-for-annoying-behavior-which-decreases-enjoyment-for-the-other-pla)

Answer (score 4):

The word you're looking for is *leech*:

> In computing and specifically Internet, a leech is one who benefits, usually deliberately, from others' information or effort but does not offer anything in return, or makes only token offerings in an attempt to avoid being called a leech.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_(computing)

In my many years of online gaming, I have had experience with such players and have always heard them referred to as the aforementioned word.

Another place to find commonly used MMO-lingo is this called [MMO Glossary](http://www.mmoglossary.com/mmorpg_terms/1/index.html), in case you need similar words.

Answer (score 1):

The world you are looking for is 'leech'. These people do nothing positive as you mentioned but benefits from everyone. I have been playing World of Warcraft for 10 years and seen plenty.

Here is a nice wikipedia page for the word:
[Leech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_(computing)). Check the gaming section.

Also, depending on the situation you can call them ninja, item.hore, killstealer.